# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: [42] in the generated java file

Tags: java, jsp

We are using jdk 1.8 with apache tomcat 8.0.12 
Trying to deploy a simple web application but getting error

```
INFO main org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina - Initialization processed in 1622 ms
INFO main org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service Catalina
INFO main org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.12
INFO tomgensoft.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig - Deploying web application archive /home/tomgenso/tomcat/webapps/tomgensoft.com/ROOT.war
ERROR tomgensoft.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig - Unable to process web resource [/WEB-INF/classes/ConnectionManager.class] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 41
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:127)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:59)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:168)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1990)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1897)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1135)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:767)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5074)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1704)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO tomgensoft.com-startStop-1 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig - Deployment of web application archive /home/tomgenso/tomcat/webapps/tomgensoft.com/ROOT.war has finished in 1,120 ms
INFO main org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina - Server startup in 1690 ms
ERROR ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-9631-exec-1 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[tomgensoft.com].[/].[jsp] - Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [42] in the generated java file: [/home/tomgenso/tomcat/work/Catalina/tomgensoft.com/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/home_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [42] in the generated java file: [/home/tomgenso/tomcat/work/Catalina/tomgensoft.com/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/home_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:446)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:335)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service
```

Comment: I don't see the UnsupportedClassVersion error in your stack trace.

Comment: The only problem here is that you didn't read the stack trace, and invented a problem instead of noticing the real one.

Answer (score 1):

`The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest` your log say's that you have not added `servet.jar` and `jsp.jar` files in your project.

and I don't find `UnsupportedClassVersion`  Major and Minor version error in your log, those errors comes because of version conflict you have to delete all class files and then build your project again.